# DevDays 2011 (London)

Tags: support, devdays-2011, devdays-london

I don't know if this is the place to ask this question. I was willing to come, but it seems all seats are taken for London. Will people in charge consider  opening  more seats?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DevDays 2011 has been cancelled](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/). So to answer your question, I don't think there will be more seats opened for London.

Comment: Cancelled? Wow..

Comment: I'm still digesting this news, but with nearly $400-worth of lost airfare and hotel, it's currently stuck in my throat...

Comment: It's because people like me, who dont buy tickets in time.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway

Answer (score 5):

A [plan B meetup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105425/140505) has been setup.

It is cheaper than the original, similar location and similar speaker lineup!