# DevDays cancelled - should we have a London meetup anyway?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011, devdays-london

As we all know, DevDays 2011 has been [cancelled](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/).

Now, I hope for everyone who already booked their travel and accommodation that they get their money back somehow. But for those who a) won't get refunds, or b) wouldn't have to travel that far anyway, or c) are in the city anyway, would anybody be interested in meeting up on a smaller scale - like a pub, or a room in a pub, or a small conference venue?

**PLEASE NOTE: The registration is ongoing at [CODE KEN London 2011](http://london2011.codeken.com), For £ 199.00**
The proposed venue has the advantage of being close to the original spot.
Fantastic work by **Jon Dickinson**.

The [meetup.com event](http://www.meetup.com/DevDays-London-2011-Plan-B/events/33387912/?a=socialmedia) originally planed by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) now redirects to Code Ken London 2011.

Why £ 199.00?

- It is a lot less than the original ticket price (500 €), for a [**similar line up**](http://london2011.codeken.com/schedule/);
- Better opportunities for networking;
- More chances to talk to speakers as the audience is smaller (80 or so people);
- You can enter the [side projects competition](http://london2011.codeken.com/side-projects/) to try and win a free ticket.

There is also a chat room [here on meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/416/pubdays-or-something-meetup-discussion) for those interested; we are using it to iron out the details, discuss availability and related stuff. Try not to get tangential.

We would really **really** like to be able to get this information to all the people who registered for the original event, so if you are reading this and you have any clout within SEIS, you might consider following up [this](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/718649#718649) request.

[image: Code Ken London 2011]

Comment: Now that the pages are down - can somebody help me out with the exact planned dates for the event please? Was ist November 1st and 2nd?

Comment: Enter [`cache:http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/london`](http://google.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdevdays.stackoverflow.com%2Flondon) in Google. It's 14-15 Nov.

Comment: Convenience link to the [general DevDays replacement meetups post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105352/with-devdays-being-cancelled-are-there-any-plans-to-facilitate-meetups-mini-conf)

Comment: Per your edit, is it wise to post an answer each with times? or should one "attendance" answer be made with, say, name: [name], free: [dates]. That way we will know who is potentially interested and when.

Comment: @Benjol: crappy late night edits are crappy ;) Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Welp, that's another one priced out of my (student) range. Also don't have time to setup a "competition" entry. Sigh.

Answer (score 25):

I could *potentially* (no promises here) sort out an evening event hosted at the Google offices - whether that's as a series of lightning talks or something similar. We already host an "Open Source Jam" periodically.

Comment: Wow, sounds *very* interesting. How many people could this accommodate? Would it be possible to do on the evening of the 14th? - although maybe the evening of sunday 13th might be attractive too. (Most out-of-towners will probably have booked flights arriving sunday to be at Excel at 7:45 the next morning)

Comment: Doing anything on a Sunday night would be somewhat harder. No idea offhand whether it could be done on the 14th, but I can investigate. I doubt whether we could host a *huge* number of people - probably less than 100 - but it could still be useful. I'll ask colleagues for more information about what's available...

Comment: cool, thanks! Even *50* would sound more than ample for a community-organized event - at least to my inexperienced ears. I was thinking about sunday for those who would have to take time off to attend monday or tuesday, but sticking to the original planned dates is probably the best way to go.

Comment: btw, I could arrange to be available all day monday if any assistance were required preparing things.

Comment: If it is anytime during week 46 (November, Monday 14th to Friday 16th), count me in (see my [answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway/105449#105449))

Comment: I already got the tickets so I'll be around London, if any help is needed I will have time to give a hand

Comment: I got the tickets too, so if I come, I'll be around for the duration. Don't know if I'd come *just* for Sunday evening though...

Comment: I would certainly show! Probably one or two more persons with me as well. Available from Sunday evening up to and including Tuesday evening.

Comment: Hi Jon, any news on the "meetup at Google London" possibility? Or can I start to book my cctvenues room for Monday afternoon, 14th November? Then I will publish that as a meetup.com event, and will see who is willing to attend.

Comment: @VonC: I haven't looked into it yet - but if you do something in the afternoon, that wouldn't conflict with an evening event anyway.

Comment: would you give your speech for that afternoon at cctvenues?

Comment: @VonC: Quite possibly - not sure at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I will mention you on the meetup.com even as "tentavite" ;)

Comment: I have created http://www.meetup.com/DevDays-London-2011-Plan-B for you and others to register. Even if the meetup ends up taking place in another location, that can at least give us an idea of the number of attendees still willing to come to a DevDays London.

Comment: @Pekka: Tom Wright has left a comment at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/#comment-61283. And he is a speaker :) I sure can use your list.

Comment: @VonC yeah, I saw that, that's great - that makes three (potential) speakers on the alternative event. Can you fire me an E-Mail re the list? I can't see yours and I'm not on Twitter

Comment: @VonC Mail returned, any alternative?

Comment: @Pekka: "mail returned"? I did receive your email list.

Comment: @VonC ah, okay then! I do get a "delivery failure" message though, I forwarded you a copy.

Comment: @Pekka: you can try the same address at gmail.com. It should work better. Note: I don't have access to my emails or meetup.com during the day. I look forward checking the registrations this evening when I get back from work.

Comment: @VonC yeah! There isn't much going on yet, though - we probably really need that E-Mail to everyone who bought tickets that SO has promised us

Comment: @Pekka: I have send an email this morning to devdays@stackexchange.com requested precisely that. I will let you know if there is any answer/follow up on that request.

Comment: @VonC http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/718263#718263

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Yes we should.

We could easily have a pub based meet up, but if we have enough volunteer speakers and attendees, a day similar to DevDays '09 might be fun. Depending on the number of interested people, we can get some central conference facilities for not a whole lot of cash monies (just a quick Google gives a nicely located 50 person room for the day, with wifi, projector and coffee for about £14 a person).

We could call it the Stack Underflow DevDay. For when there's just not enough interest in the real deal.

**Edit**: So, I'd rather do a weekday evening than a weekend (but I could make a Sunday, I guess) - 13th, 14th and 15th November are fine for me. The key thing now is to work out how many people are interested in attending. Maybe some kind of poll with options like:

1. An all day event, like DevDays '09. 6 or 7 45 minute talks with 10 minutes for questions. Spilling into pubs afterwards. Probably costing around £20 a head without lunch.
2. An afternoon event. 5 or 6 30 minute talks, pub afterwards. Probably still about £15 a head.
3. An evening event with 3 or 4 15 minute talks. Probably free, or marginal cost.
4. A pub meetup/meal setup. Free, but not as in beer.

If it turns out that only 10 or 15 people are around, options 3 and 4 seems better. If 100 odd people are interested, then we need to see if we can grab some speakers.

Comment: That sounds great! I, for one, would be more than willing to sign up and send £14 (or whatever) beforehand if somebody can organize this locally, and I'm sure many others would be, too. I'm sure we could get some sponsoring from SE, Inc. as well.

Comment: Cost is not a big issue for me (assuming the refund from SE comes through!), but I don't think I'd come for anything other than option 1 or 2.

Comment: Would you consider registering at http://t.co/nmD9V10 ?

Comment: Love the name: "Stack Underflow"

Answer (score 7):

I will be in London next November 14th and 15th. I can be there for a Sunday evening event as well.
(I am the French correspondent of a London-based team, usually working in Paris France, but for that specific week, I have to work at their London office anyway)

If you are still interested in the talk "DVCS in big corporation", based on the SO answer to "[Distributed Version Control Systems and the Enterprise - a Good mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757)", I can make that presentation.
**8 other speakers will do the same FOR TWO DAYS**: See

- [meetup.com event](http://www.meetup.com/DevDays-London-2011-Plan-B/events/33387912/), and now:
- **[Code Ken London 2011](http://london2011.codeken.com/)** (the new name for what was SO DevDays London 2011).
  (Thanks to the increadible work of [Jon Dickinson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway/106432#106432))

I am looking right now for a conference venue, asking for rates at http://www.cctvenues.co.uk/

I got around 850€ for half a day (no catering), up to 90 attendees in theater-style room with wifi. I will have updated quotes for two days soon:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes Sir! I'd be very interested in hearing this one, and I'm sure others will, too. Let us know when you get a response about the venue.

Comment: I only found the full speakers page on Tuesday, and all of a sudden was looking forward to hearing/meeting you. Then Black Wednesday happened...

Comment: @Benjol: could you still be in London next November 14th? Because if you do, you might still hearing/meeting me. And I still plan at least half a day conference.

Comment: Hm, let me see, 850€ divided by, what, 5? That's going to be a bit expensive as things currently stand :)

Comment: @Benjol: no, divided by 80 to 90 people, once we will have advertised it on, for instance, meetup.com (plus SO can take part of it as a sponsorship, I suppose). Things "currently stands" only if we do nothing about it.

Comment: VonC, I did actually reply to the cancellation mail, requesting that Joel send out a mail to all the people who had signed up to London Devdays, pointing them to this question. I don't know if he'll get the mail though. I figure it's the least they can do. If you have any leverage, you might like to try too...

Comment: @Benjol: excellent :) As the 8th user of ALL TIME on Stack Overflow, I have... err... nothing. No leverage at all ;) But I will email them as well.

Comment: VonC, in the current economic climate, it is reassuring to know that the market value of SO reputation is so high :)

Answer (score 7):

London Dev Days Resurrected... or something like that!

Following on from VonC's initiative I've been in touch with VonC, Jon Skeet and the other presenters to see if they are available to continue with the original line up. So far we have confirmation from half of the presenters and we are working on the rest.

I am in talks with a sponsor that would help take the risk out of the venue hire.

Alison from Stack Exchange has agreed to publicise the event to the people that originally signed up to London Dev Days, once we get a program published. I'm hopeful that this will happen towards the end of next week.

We'll let you know when there is more news.

See you all at Dev Days Resurrected!

Comment: That is great news! I have a good feeling about this. Let us know if there's anything we can do to help.

Comment: Jon, thanks so much for saving my airfare and hotel booking! Please keep us posted on when the videos come online (I missed the concurrency talk), and for CodeKen2012 :)  You may be interested in Pekka's question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112683/codeken-2011-where-was-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 3):

I need to be in London anyway some time this year, and I might as well stick to the original plan.

This is not a 100% commitment yet - I haven't any tickets booked at the moment. But I would be ready to commit if there's a decent turnout, a location settled on, and bookings in place.

Unfortunately, due to lack of local presence and knowledge, I'm unable to assist in finding a pub or other place to be at. All I can contribute is be there, either on the initially planned monday and tuesday, or one or two days prior, and the guarantee to pay my share of the costs.

I could make myself available to help with preparations sunday or monday.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't started trying to get refunds yet.

I'm not sure if I'd commit to two (work) days, if it's just for an hour and a half in a pub (even though I'd love to meet you guys). But if I really can't get refunds, I might consider it.

Thanks for the thought anyway.

**Attendance: I'll be in town from Sunday early evening, but my return trip is on Tuesday evening.** I'm not sure if I can justify the two days off that my employer has given me for just a Sunday evening event.

Comment: Would you consider registering at http://t.co/nmD9V10 ?

Comment: @VonC, blocked from here, but done anyway :)

Comment: Hehe, made a $40 dollar profit from the exchange rate change between when I paid and when I got reimbursed...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add to this thread rather than the chat room but there is a minimum reputation before you can post there. I am from London and would be interested in coming to an afternoon / all day event in that week if one could be arranged.

Comment: Would you still consider registering at http://t.co/nmD9V10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Great job guys! I was really bummed out when I heard this was cancelled.

Getting to London is fairly easy for me and I'd already blocked out the Monday and Tuesday in my diary. I was scheduled to speak about my research and would be more than happy to do so at any "Plan B" event, if people wanted me to.

My area of research is Sensory Substitution and I was planning on writing a talk that blended some neuroscience/psychology with some of the unique design/development problems that are inherent to the area.

If I was going to talk, would people want more of an oddball talk? Or more of a focus on serious programming?

Comment: Great, I would *love* to hear this one, the topic sounds fascinating! Re oddball vs. serious, if in doubt, I tend to go for the oddball :) Could you elaborate a bit more in which way the two extremes would differ?

Comment: @Tom, I'll take the blend please. Shaken, not stirred :)

Comment: Tom, really enjoyed your talk. Of course my judgement is totally uninfluenced by having won the 'competition' :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks @Benjol! Glad you enjoyed it. Of course I'm also very relieved that 2 people volunteered!