# Will there be a StackOverflow DevDays 2012?

Tags: discussion, devdays

I just found out that DevDays 2011 ended up getting [canceled](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/).

Also no information [here](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/).

So is anything planned yet for 2012?  The googles, pipes and tubes have failed me!

Comment: The first one was cancelled due to the amount of time that was put forth to prep it.  So chances are short term there probably will not be one.  If there was one for 2012 it should of already been mentioned.  Big events like these take a lot of effort and planning.

Comment: Although, a lesser (London only) but nonetheless awesome [code-ken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway) was orchestrated quickly.

Comment: I already mentioned http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132536/codeken-2012-would-you-consider-being-a-speaker for London in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

CodeKen are set to do another [dev days](http://london2011.codeken.com/codeken-2012/partners.html) in London, and are sponsored by Careers and SO.

Comment: I confirm: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132536/codeken-2012-would-you-consider-being-a-speaker