# CodeKen 2012: would you consider being a speaker?

Tags: discussion, devdays

In 2011, CodeKen brilliantly took the place of ([then cancelled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105425/devdays-cancelled-should-we-have-a-london-meetup-anyway)) DevDays2011 for London:
See [CodeKen 2011](http://london2011.codeken.com/codeken-2012/codeken-2011.html) and my [own report](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106661248019508703534/posts/9Zd3r96XPwo).

[Jon Dickinson](https://plus.google.com/106595912319775839298/posts), the organizer for CodeKen events, asks me to publish here the following request:

> Following on from the great reception to CodeKen 2011, **CodeKen 2012 will run this year on the 6th and 7th of November**.
>   The venue is booked, [**SO is supporting the event**](http://london2011.codeken.com/codeken-2012/partners.html) to help make it a success, the tickets are available for sale.
>
> The next step is to get a line up of fantastic speakers organized.
>   The call for presentations can be found on the conference site: See "[**Speakers**](http://codeken.com/codeken-2012/speakers.html)".
>   If would like to present at CodeKen 2012 then we would love to receive your talk suggestion, just fill in the form on the speakers section of the site.

So, would you consider speaking at such an event?

Comment: +1 CodeKen 2011 was great. Excellent organisation, great talks, cool people, nice food, and it saved my non-refundable plane and hotel bookings!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. We're starting to get some presentations come in and I'm looking forward to another eclectic conference celebrating software development.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Programmers, **if** even there?

Comment: Speakers generally want to know things like "are you covering any of my expenses?" (conference admission, hotel, travel...) and "how long are the sessions" - adding a few more details to the page would help.

Comment: @KateGregory most details are here: http://london2011.codeken.com/codeken-2012/ There will be completed when available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally unqualified, but something about Raspberry Pi would be really interesting...

Comment: And what about the Gooseberry ? ;) ( http://www.gizmodo.fr/2012/06/22/bonne-alternative-raspberry-pi.html via http://liliputing.com/2012/06/gooseberry-developer-boards-40-alternative-raspberry-pi.html )